# Need to remove trailing 0s from decimal number in string using regex

Tags: java, regex

This is my regex:

```
((((?<=(\d\.)(([1-9]))))|((?<=\d)\.[0])))((0)+)
```

This is my Description:

```
af 0.044 00.22 44.3500,44.334000,0.5000,1.750,1.9000,0.1480,10.2500,0.7480",19.00 MM,62.00MM,12MM,12.0000MM,DRILL BIT,0.040',1.00 IN MINI BEND RADIUS|0.3120IN TIP DIA|36.00 IN LG,45MM,45.0000MM,30MM,30.0000MM,40MM,40.0000MM,40.00 15.20,40.00,15.20000:14.00,40.00;15.20000*14.00X40.00/15.20000(14.00),40.00\15.20000{14.00},40.00|15.20000[14.00],40.00?15.20000%14.00,15.20000{14.00},40.00|15.20000,15.20000%14.00, 345.00 354.34500aa 354.aa 354. ABC.000 17.0
```

As per requirement it should removing trailing 0's from the description.The above regex is removing the zeros but failing in some conditions. Like its failing on if value is `0.040`,  can anyone suggest me a better regex which would satisfy all the conditions.

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: Try [`replaceAll("\\.?0+(?![0-9.])", "")`](https://regex101.com/r/vC8vK6/1)

Comment: I need to build a regex which should be able to remove all the trailing 0s where evere present in the description

Comment: @AbhayKant: But you need to precise. What about `354.`? Is `ABC.000` to be touched? Please post the expected output.

Comment: This is working fine but failing in condition if value is:-   ABC.00

Comment: if 354. is in last of the description the it should be treated as a full stop. Else it should give the output as 354 removing the decimal.

Comment: What about [`"(?<!\\d\\.)\\.?0+(?![\\d.])`](https://regex101.com/r/vC8vK6/2)? This ping-pong will go on if you do not clarify the requirements.

Comment: this is my description :- 0.000 1.000 2.020 3.0005 5.43040000004 4.4004.00000 0.040- ABC.00af 0.044 00.22 44.3500,44.334000,0.5000,1.750,1.9000,0.1480,10.2500,0.7480",19.00 MM,62.00MM,12MM,12.0000MM,DRILL BIT,0.040',1.00 IN MINI BEND RADIUS|0.3120IN TIP DIA|36.00 IN LG,45MM,45.0000MM,30MM,30.0000MM,40MM,40.0000MM,40.00 15.20,40.00,15.20000:14.00,40.00;15.20000*14.00X40.00/15.20000(14.00),40.00\15.20000{14.00},40.00|15.20000[14.00],40.00?15.20000%14.00,15.20000{14.00},40.00|15.20000,15.20000%14.00, 345.00 354.34500aa 354.aa 354.0, ABC.000 17.0.

Comment: This should be the expected outpt :- 0.000 1.000 2.020 3.0005 5.43040000004 4.4004.00000 0.040- ABC.00af 0.044 00.22 44.3500,44.334000,0.5000,1.750,1.9000,0.1480,10.2500,0.7480",19.00 MM,62.00MM,12MM,12.0000MM,DRILL BIT,0.040',1.00 IN MINI BEND RADIUS|0.3120IN TIP DIA|36.00 IN LG,45MM,45.0000MM,30MM,30.0000MM,40MM,40.0000MM,40.00 15.20,40.00,15.20000:14.00,40.00;15.20000*14.00X40.00/15.20000(14.00),40.00\15.20000{14.00},40.00|15.20000[14.00],40.00?15.20000%14.00,15.20000{14.00},40.00|15.20000,15.20000%14.00, 345.00 354.34500aa 354.aa 354, ABC.000 17.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = s.replaceAll("(\\d\\.\\d*[1-9])0+\\b", "$1")
     .replaceAll("(\\d)\\.0+\\b", "$1");
```

For the two cases 1.034000 to 1.034 and 1.000

Answer (score 1):

Based on the expected results of your comments you just want to remove the `.0` from decimals that end with them.
In that case this should work:

```
s = s.replaceAll("([0-9])+[.][0](?![0-9])", "$1");
```

Hence : `123.0` becomes `123`

To do a bit more thourough 0-cleaning.
A bit of lazy matching and a negative lookahead could do the job.

```
0*([0-9]+[.][0-9][0-9]*?)0+(?![0-9])
```

For this test example:

```
String s = "0.010 00.20200,003.30330;10044.04400M,5.0";
s = s.replaceAll("0*([0-9]+[.][0-9][0-9]*?)0+(?![0-9])", "$1");
```

s will return:

```
0.01 0.202,3.3033;10044.044M,5.0
```